# React useState loading not changing

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I run into errors attempting to display data that has not been fetched yet, so.. I want to display loading until the data is fetched, but my 'setIsLoading' always returns false even when it's set to true.

Am I missing something really obvious? I'm fairly fresh to hooks.

```
const Pokedex = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const pokemonId = 1;

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const result = await axios(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`
      );

      setData(result.data);
    };

    fetchData();
    setIsLoading(false);
  }, [pokemonId]);

  console.log("loading: ", isLoading);
```

Comment: That's because `fetchData` is async. Put `setIsLoading(false)` inside `fetchData` after `setData`.

Comment: Can you verify if the effect is even being executed? You can text this by inserting a `console.log` inside the useEffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `isLoading` state right after the fetch request completes.

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {
    const result = await axios(
      `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`
    );

    setData(result.data);
    setIsLoading(false);
  };

  fetchData();
}, []);
```

Don't rely on printing stuff outside the hooks because you won't have a real feedback. You can use render method (in the return, with JSX code) or inside the hooks.

Also, since state is reset when the component is refreshed, you can rely on initializating `isLoading` to `true`. That way you just need to change it once the request is fetched.

You can check a working demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-forest-owwbd?file=/src/Pokedex.js).

Comment: Thank you! Moving where I set the loading to false fixed my issues, and thanks for the explanation! 
If anyone else looks at this example, your demo is currently broken because it's got an extra useEffect call below the export but.. it can just be deleted.

Comment: Glad it helped. And thanks for letting me know about the example. I copied the hook to have top-level indentation to copy it over in SO, but forgot to remove it. Silly me :p. It's fixed now

Answer (score 0):

First of all, If you are calling async function, you are anonymously creating `Promise<void>`, so after that, good way to check if promise was successfull is to use `then` or `catch` methods from **Promise API**.

Example solution.

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    const result = await axios(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`);

    setData(result.data);
};

fetchData().then(() => {
    setIsLoading(false)
})
```

Comment: I'm familiar with then/catch, that is probably a cleaner more explicit way of writing it though, thanks! But my initial issue still remains it's actually never set to true in the beginning when set it in the fetchData function.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your loading state should be initialized to `true`.

```
const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
```

And then, set the loading state to `false` inside the async function

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios(
        `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${pokemonId}`
      );

      setData(result.data);
      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, [pokemonId]);
```